# How to connect to Azure VM SQL Server Analysis Service Instance using a Developer Computer

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2013, ssms, sql-data-tools

I need a way to connect to an SQL Server Analysis Service default instance on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine from my developer computer at home. I understand that i can only connect to Analysis Service using Windows Authentication and i haven't been able to figure that out. However, i managed to connect to the SQL Server Database Engine using SQL Server Authentication.

This is how i have Azure environment is setup:

[image]

To setup my connection to SQL Server Database Engine using SQL Server Authentication, i created an Endpoint in Microsoft Azure Management Portal with port 1433 for private, and a random port for public. I have done the same process for Analysis Service on port 2383 but still no luck. Without this connection, i don't think i will be able to deploy BI Cubes.

[Here is the Link to the blog that help with this.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/)

How can i setup my Virtual Machine so that i will be able to connect to Analysis Service using SQL Management Studio and or Visual Studio 2013? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess i will just have to develop my apps within Azure VMs, since i can have my VMs talk to each other using Active Directory, it doesn't look like i will get help to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Analysis Services works with AD accounts, as your developer machine is not on the same domain as the VM running Analysis Services, you will need to use the runas tool with the /netonly parameter to run the applications such as Visual Studio or SQL Mgmt Studio so that you can be authenticated correctly.

When I need to do this, I create a shortcut on my desktop with the command as follows:

```
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\myusername "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

or

```
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\myusername "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

When you run the short cut you will get a command prompt that will ask you for the password for the account you are running as and then the program will open.

From there you can use it normally

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Do you know how to deploy solution using VS 2019? I get error: "The server could not be contacted."

Answer (score 0):

You still can process cubes in your vm's ssas instance.

- Step 1 : Build your Cube's project in your local system
- Step 2 : open your project location and copy .sadatabase
- Step 3 : create xmla script using analysis service deployment wizard
- step 4 : open the script in ssms and execute